# Angular 4 - Saving form data of highly complex form

Tags: forms, angular, rest, save

We have highly complex form in Angular 4 and we want to be able to save form data as an object to be able to send to our DB and also to external APis in json.

Form has tabbed form wizard format and each tab had lot of form controls and each tab itself is very complex. 
So we plan to create a data service where at each step, we plan to put data in an object, and keep updating as we nagivate till the end. If user clicks save drafts at any time in form wizard, current state of form data object will go in DB.
Form next, previous work same way, retrieve or updating form data object.

When saving form or submitting form, we will have post http call to backend.

Is there any better approach to achieve this? or we are following right direction. Any examples will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No better approach. You put your complete model in the service. Than create sub-models inside that model that correspond to your individual tabs. In each component, get the model from the service, and keep updating the appropriate model for the tab you are on.